# converting sf to raster using predefined cell size and plot it

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, tmap

`nz_height` and `nz` are present in `spData` package.

1. `nz_height` - sf class dataset - Top 101 highest points in New Zealand.
2. `nz` - sf class data - Polygons representing the 16 regions of New Zealand.

Below is the plot for visualization using `tmap()`

Can you please help me create

1. nz_raster (raster class) with cell size = 100km by 100km and each cell contains number of peaks in it
2. plot nz_raster.

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(spData)
library(tmap)


# vector plot of peaks
tm_shape(nz) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "white") + 
  tm_shape(nz_height) + 
  tm_symbols(col = "red") + 
  tm_scale_bar()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rasterize the points with the `raster` package or with its successor `terra`:

```
# Load packages
packs <- list("tidyverse", "raster", "sf", "terra")
lapply(packs, require, character.only = T)

# raster version
nz_height <- st_transform(nz_height, crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>% 
  as("Spatial")
nz_raster <- raster(resolution = 100000, crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", 
  xmn = 13600000, xmx = 15100000, ymn = -5300000, ymx = -4700000) %>% 
  rasterize(nz_height, ., field = "elevation", fun = "count", background = 0)

# terra version
nz_height <- st_transform(nz_height, crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>% 
  vect()
nz_raster <- rast(resolution = 100000, crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", 
  xmin = 13600000, xmax = 15100000, ymin = -5300000, ymax = -4700000) %>% 
  rasterize(nz_height, ., fun = length, background = 0)
```

The code uses a Mollweide equal area projection, i.e. the grid cells are equally large.

You can plot the raster object via the `plot()` function that is part of these packages. Other options are e.g. `rasterVis::gplot()`, `ggplot2::geom_raster()`, and `tmap::tm_raster()`.